# How can I update events

Tags: civievent

How can I update events already set up? Please send me the steps to update the informationon the events page.I am unsure the steps for updating the page.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE. I think you should find all this in the docs at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest

But quick answer is, in the back end, select **Manage Events** in the **Events** menu. They select **Configure** for the event in question. Should be obvious from there...